# Angular - pagination without user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination

Apologies, the title is horrifically worded.

**Background**

I have an angular app which I am using as a static display. There is no user interaction so most is based on timeouts. Page is loaded, after X amount of time based on X elements, the page reloads.

**Issue**

I want to show/hide only portions at at time. For example, one hundred results and I show 10, wait ten seconds, then show the next ten. Again, no user input though.

I am having trouble sorting the elements and hiding/displaying. From my understanding, I believe it is best to use a filter for this similar to pagination with buttons but then how do I trigger that automatically?

I use a JavaScript function to handle fade outs and window reset but I am lost.
I need something like..

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filtered = items | filter:search | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit"> -->
```

## Solution

The limitTo and startFrom directives worked perfectly, in my controller I setup a $interval using the angular service and iterated "pages"..

```
startFrom:currentFlowerPage*flowerPageSize | limitTo: flowerPageSize
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to AngularJS v1.4.0 or higher, you can use the `limitTo` filter to get the behavior you want.

```
<li class="visible" ng-repeat="x in items | limitTo:entryLimit:entryLimit*currentPage">
```

you can manipulate `entryLimit` and `currentPage` with`$timeout` as you please to play around with the page number and page size.

[AngularJS v1.4.0 limitTo filter doc](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/filter/limitTo)